# How to create Panorama Picture with PHP?

Tags: php, image, webcam, panoramas

I have multiple images I get from a web cam, this works all fine. But now I need to create a Panorama Picture from them and save it. I was able to place all the images next to each other and save the new big image but there is no thing as fade in. The new Big “Panorama” just doesn’t look nice.
Can anyone tellme how to create a nice Panorama Picture from multiple Images?

Thanks &Regards

Comment: have a look at ImageMagic http://www.skeptic.de/PHP_Tutorials/imagick.htm

Comment: Hi, looks interesting. I will have a look at this. Thank you :)